# Responding to client disconnects using bottle and gevent.wsgi?

Tags: python, wsgi, bottle, gevent

I have a small asynchronous server implemented using [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/) and [gevent.wsgi](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.wsgi.html).  There is a routine used to implement long poll that looks pretty much like the "Event Callbacks" example in the [bottle documentation](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/async.html#event-callbacks):

```
def worker(body):
  msg = msgbus.recv()
  body.put(msg)
  body.put(StopIteration)

@route('/poll')
def poll():
  body = gevent.queue.Queue()
  worker = gevent.spawn(worker, body)
  return body
```

Here, `msgbus` is a ZMQ `sub` socket.

This all works fine, but if a client breaks the connection while
`worker` is blocked on `msgbus.recv()`, that greenlet task will hang
around "forever" (well, until a message is received), and will only
find out about the disconnected client when it attempts to send a
response.

I can use `msgbus.poll(timeout=something)` if I don't want to block
forever waiting for ipc messages, but I still can't detect a client
disconnect.

What I *want* to do is get something like a reference to the client
socket so that I can use it in some kind of `select` or `poll` loop,
or get some sort of asynchronous notification inside my greenlet, but
I'm not sure how to accomplish either of these things with these
frameworks (bottle and gevent).

Is there a way to get notified of client disconnects?

Answer (score 1):

Aha!  The `wsgi.input` variable, at least under `gevent.wsgi`, has an `rfile` member that is a file-like object.  This doesn't appear to be required by the [WSGI spec](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/#environ-variables), so it might not work with other servers.

With this I was able to modify my code to look something like:

```
def worker(body, rfile):
  poll = zmq.Poller()
  poll.register(msgbus)
  poll.register(rfile, zmq.POLLIN)

  while True:
    events = dict(poll.poll())

    if rfile.fileno() in events:
      # client disconnect!
      break

    if msgbus in events:
      msg = msgbus.recv()
      body.put(msg)
      break

    body.put(StopIteration)

@route('/poll')
def poll():
  rfile = bottle.request.environ['wsgi.input'].rfile
  body = gevent.queue.Queue()
  worker = gevent.spawn(worker, body, rfile)
  return body
```

And this works great...

...except on [OpenShift](http://www.openshift.com/), where you will have to use the
[alternate frontend](https://www.openshift.com/blogs/paas-websockets) on port 8000 with websockets support.