# dealing with server side event disconnections

Tags: python, bottle, server-sent-events

I have a simple python bottle application that emits SSE events to a javascript listener.

This works without problems until the client 'goes away' via a browser refresh or page back etc.

Because the events from the application are delivered and then removed from an internal queue, one or two events are lost when the server tries to send them to a client that is no longer there.

I don't want the events to be lost, but I cannot currently see a way to fix this in a sensible manner.

I plan to switch to web sockets instead and use an event - acknowledgement model to solve the problem unless there is something I could do with the SSE to prevent the events from being lost in this way.

It seems to me that SEE may not be designed for my particular use case in mind.

Here is the code I am using:

```
@route('/stream/events')
def event_stream():
    response.content_type  = 'text/event-stream'
    response.cache_control = 'no-cache'
    # Set client-side auto-reconnect timeout, ms.
    yield 'retry: 1000\n\n'

    while True:
        event = event_queue.get()
        logging.debug("Received event from hal: %s", event)
        yield "data: " + json.dumps(event) + "\n\n"
```

A link to my solution for the problem can be found here. It uses weak references to 'detect' when a client has gone away, aswell as individual queues per SEE connection: http://blog.jason.spashett.com/python-bottle-server-side-events-one-way-to-handle-client-disconnects.html

Comment: Could you priovide a piece of code how you emit there events?

Comment: @wenzul It is imporant that events are not missed becuase a user presses a hardware switch on the running device, and it should generate an event on a web page. This is for a hardware test. It's undesirable therefore to have any events go astray, and this can happen when the client changes page. I will attempt to trap navigation away from page, but it doesn't seem robust enough. This is one-way communication I need, but I also need to know the event is delivered therefore I may well need to introduce an acknowledgement.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies, most helpful. I likes @baynezy 's blog post. Between all the answers I have come to realise what is wrong. Messages are being sent to a stale SEE connection, a new SEE connection comes in on page refresh, but I have only one queue, which items are removed from and delivered. I belive that having a ques for each client connection, which picks events up from a main queue may well solve the problem. I found the problem confusing as I have one web browser client and will only ever have one, however there are two connections, one stale, and one new.

Comment: Useful links to implement a queue for each http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/async.html#event-callbacks and http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/116/.

Comment: Thanks for the link @wenzul I have seen that. One crucial thing is missing for my application in particular; I use queues to store events, and must delete them when the client connection is broken. But there is no obvious way to do this with Bottle. So I have come up with the following scheme that uses weak references: http://silly-walking-creatures.blogspot.co.uk/2015/08/python-bottle-server-side-events-one.html  I see that detecting a disconnect is a common thing people try to achieve.

Comment: What about that workaround? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20110830/responding-to-client-disconnects-using-bottle-and-gevent-wsgi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to persist the events on your server so that on a reconnection or a page refresh you can retrieve them.

I talk about this subject in a blog post.

http://bayn.es/real-time-web-apps-with-server-sent-events-pt-2/

Answer (score 0):

SSE (Server Sent Events, part of HTML 5 specification) are like a radio broadcast: once events are emitted, they are forgotten by the server.

It's a very good way of sending information from the server to clients, but **it's only one-way**.

As it is not possible to reliably detect client disconnection, in your use case a possible solution indeed is to do a kind of acknowledgement like you suggest. **Web sockets are ok for this since it is a two-ways communication technique.**

However you can think of another scheme, combining SSE with another mechanism, for example: client could emit an AJAX request every time an event is received (acknowledgement). In order to minimize latency due to connection time, you can use keep-alive requests. It depends on the frequency of your events, in case of a lot of events per second forget about this.

Comment: Not entirely true. Client can send the server the ID of the last message it received, so the server may resume the stream. Problem is that quite often SSE handlers do not send IDs...